# c# trigger/call events from another control

Tags: c#, events

In VFP9, if i have two buttons (butt1 & butt2) If i want to trigger butt2 click event from butt1 i just do this from butt1 `click` event `butt2.click()` and it will call whatever code i have in the procedure/event in butt2. How do i do that in c#?

> How do I call event of a certain control from another control like
>   below

.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.click()
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the handler directly like this `button1_Click(button1, null);`

**Example Usage:**

```
Button button1;
Button button2;

public Form1()
{
    button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);

}

void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1_Click(button1, null);
}
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Action when click occurs
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to simulate button click, if you just want to execute some logic?
Wrap this logic into separate method, an call it from click handlers you choose:

```
private Foo1() {}

private Foo2() {}

private button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Foo1();
  Foo2();
}

private button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Foo2();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just bind the button1 click event to button2 click event in `form_load` or `designer.cs`
`button2.Click+=new EventHandler(button1_Click);`